# How to check whether force quit has disabled notifications

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift

I am working on an app that, among other things, provides alarms in emergencies. Users can toggle a setting to have alarms be put through even if their iPhone is muted, but this service has another hurdle to leap: when the app has been force quit, it cannot receive (content-available) notifications until the app is relaunched by the user.

There is a geofencing event in place which buys me some processing time even if the app has been force quit, and in that time, I would like to check if such a block is in place, and if so, request the user to open their app again, and not aggressively force-quit in the future. (Many people still think it's just a way to keep things clean, even though it actually costs you battery life to not just leave apps in the background)

SO THE CORE OF THE PROBLEM: I need an (API call? Something else?) that will tell me whether the app is in such a 'force quit, cannot receive notifications' state, assuming that I do have processing time to do this check.

Anything is welcome, I have not been able to find proper Apple documentation on the notifications block.

Thank you very much.

Comment: @merjin you are talking about remote notifications are Local Notifications ?

Comment: @RahulMishra Remote notifications. Notifications with the content-available flag that trigger events inside the app's code.

Answer (score 0):

While there is no API I am aware of to find state *after*, you can infer the state just *before* the application is terminated, and record that.

**Code**

```
applicationDidEnterBackground
```

will be called when an app has received a terminate signal.

**More Info**

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10200505/which-function-is-called-when-iphone-app-is-terminated) describes what lifecycle functions to use, and

Comment: I've looked into events like that before, but it turns out that when the app is force quit from the background, there is no event. It's a silent kill in that situation.

Comment: To be more specific, it's a silent kill when the app is suspended. I'm afraid that's still something I want to account for, though, since even a suspended app can receive notifications, but a force-quit-ed one cannot.