# What method of AppDelegate will be called after entering into Suspended state?

Tags: ios, background, lifecycle

My App goes in background, If I open again, It shows same page where I left it.

While, If iOS puts app into Suspended state, yet it is in memory. If I come back, which AppDelegate methods will be called.

Actually my purpose is to restore same screen from suspended to app, if it is not TERMINATED.

**Last thing, Will didFinishLaunchWithOptions will be called if App is returning from SUSPENDED state.?**

Thanks..

Comment: In my opinion, it's better to use [Preserving and Restoring State](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/PreservingandRestoringState.html) feature of iOS in this case.

Comment: What if App is killed and than started, will it go to restored ViewController or it will start from first? @dive

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/TheAppLifeCycle/TheAppLifeCycle.html) states,

> - application:willFinishLaunchingWithOptions:—This method is your app’s    first chance to execute code at launch time.
> - application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:—This method allows you to    perform any final initialization before your app is displayed to
>     the    user.
> - applicationDidBecomeActive:—Lets your app know that it is about to    become the foreground app. Use this method for any last minute
>     preparation.
> - applicationWillResignActive:—Lets you know that your app is    transitioning away from being the foreground app. Use this method to
>     put your app into a quiescent state.
> - applicationDidEnterBackground:—Lets you know that your app is now    running in the background and may be suspended at any time.
> - applicationWillEnterForeground:—Lets you know that your app is moving    out of the background and back into the foreground, but that
>     it is    not yet active.
> - applicationWillTerminate:—Lets you know that your app is being    terminated. This method is not called if your app is suspended.

so `applicationWillEnterForeground` and `applicationWillResignActive` will be get called!

Answer (score 1):

```
- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application {
// Sent when the application is about to move from active to inactive state. This can occur for certain types of temporary interruptions (such as an incoming phone call or SMS message) or when the user quits the application and it begins the transition to the background state.
// Use this method to pause ongoing tasks, disable timers, and invalidate graphics rendering callbacks. Games should use this method to pause the game.
}


- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application {
// Use this method to release shared resources, save user data, invalidate timers, and store enough application state information to restore your application to its current state in case it is terminated later.
// If your application supports background execution, this method is called instead of applicationWillTerminate: when the user quits.
}


- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application {
// Called as part of the transition from the background to the active state; here you can undo many of the changes made on entering the background.
}


- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application {
// Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive. If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the user interface.
}


- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application {
// Called when the application is about to terminate. Save data if appropriate. See also applicationDidEnterBackground:.
}
```

`didFinishLaunchWithOptions` didnt call.

Answer (score 1):

Accoding to [application's life cycle](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/TheAppLifeCycle/TheAppLifeCycle.html), Your app will not get any notification when ios will put your app in suspended mode. Whenever your app enters in background mode and if its not doing anything - not processing - ios will put it in suspended state.
But when suspended and its still in memory, You don't really need to do anything to display same screen where your app was before. ios automatically keep the state of app. You need to manage this only if your app is getting terminate while in suspended mode ..i.e. not in memory.

If you don't have any execution in background with any of [background execution](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH4-SW1) method , you can consider app in suspended mode if you receive notification for `applicationDidEnterBackground`  store state of your app somewhere and `applicationWillEnterForeground` you can display app with stored state.

or if you are executing some finite task in background, You can keep local variable and use that for keeping track of suspended or now. on `applicationDidEnterBackground`, `variable  = inBackground`,  when you task completed and `variable  == inBackground`,  set `variable  == inSuspended`  and also store state of your app somewhere.  on  `applicationWillEnterForeground`

```
 if  variable  == inSuspended
   {
    //Display app according to previously stored state.
   `variable  == inForgorund`,  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can test it your self using breakpoints in AppDelegate file.

If user will click on Home button once, app is in suspended state.
If user will click on Home button twice, app is in inactive state.

While user comes from suspended state to the app, I found following method calls.

first : `applicationWillEnterForeground` then `applicationDidBecomeActive`.

`didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` not called.

[More details](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29914605/3411787)