# How to call a method when my IOS app is closed

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to remove data from a Firebase database that I have set up when a user closes an app. Is there a method that is called when the app is closed in order for me to call one last function to remove the data from the database?

Thanks

Comment: To Close application using double time press home button and swipe Up is different thing and press home button and application will work on background is different task. Maybe you are looking for `- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application` method

Comment: I am looking for a method that will be called when the home button is double tapped and then the app is swiped up

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10200505/which-function-is-called-when-iphone-app-is-terminated

Comment: Looks like first you tap home button single time and then press home button twice and kill app. In that case `applicationWillTerminate` will not be called as app is in suspended state. It will call when your app is open and double press home button and kill your app.

Answer (score 5):

To Close application using double time press home button and swipe Up is different thing. It will call below method

```
- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application {
}
```

Press home button and application will work on background is different task. Maybe you are looking for

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application{
}
```

Please refer [TheAppLifeCycle](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/TheAppLifeCycle/TheAppLifeCycle.html)

1. **application:willFinishLaunchingWithOptions**:—This method is your app’s first chance to execute code at launch time.
2. **application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions**:—This method allows you to perform any final initialization before your app is displayed to the user.
3. **applicationDidBecomeActive**:—Lets your app know that it is about to become the foreground app. Use this method for any last minute preparation.
4. **applicationWillResignActive**:—Lets you know that your app is transitioning away from being the foreground app. Use this method to put your app into a quiescent state.
5. **applicationDidEnterBackground**:—Lets you know that your app is now running in the background and may be suspended at any time.
6. **applicationWillEnterForeground**:—Lets you know that your app is moving out of the background and back into the foreground, but that it is not yet active.
7. **applicationWillTerminate**:—Lets you know that your app is being terminated. This method is not called if your app is suspended.

Hope it will help you.

Answer (score 1):

use this `appdelegate` method

```
- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application {
}
```

Or 
erase data in Every application launch, because  `applicationWillTerminate`
only get called in restricted conditions.

Comment: I tried doing this and I couldn't get it to work. Is there a trick to it?

Comment: you code not working in this method? or applicationWillTerminate not getting called

Comment: I put a print method inside of applicationWillTerminate, yet when I close the app on my phone, the debugger simply disappears. I tried placing the code inside that method, but it did not remove it from the database.

Comment: I don't know, your exact requirment. why you are not on Application launch

Comment: What do you mean by Application launch?

Answer (score 0):

Firebase supports some functions regarding presence.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/ios/firebasedatabase/api/reference/Classes/FIRDatabaseReference#/c:objc(cs)FIRDatabaseReference(im)onDisconnectRemoveValue

If you want to remove a node on disconnect. `ref.onDisconnectRemoveValue()`

Or if you want to set a value on a node: `ref.onDisconnectSetValue(someValue)`